# MongoDB server connection

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

What is the difference between the following ways of connecting to MongoDB server?

```
MongoServer mongo  = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://192.168.11.237:27017")
```

and

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://192.168.11.237:27017");
mongo.TryConnect();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using not official driver. So official driver you can get [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/downloads).
And in official driver you should use:

```
MongoServer mongo  = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://192.168.11.237:27017")
```

This driver will manage connetions internally, so you no need to care about this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Createmethod):

> Create maintains a table of MongoServer instances it has returned before, so if you call Create again with the same parameters you get the same instance back again.

I assume that you're referring to the TryConnect method from the second [MongoDB driver](https://github.com/lanwin/mongodb-csharp/blob/5e4a16b48dbed379cc02df918739b982b143dc3a/MongoDBDriver/Mongo.cs#L94). TryConnect tries to connect to the database and returns a bool, telling you if the attempt was successful or not. This way you don't have to write exception handling yourself.